# Is there any way to customize the JMeter report?

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I have my JMeter scripts (.jmx) ready to run a performance test.
The script works fine and the HTML reports are generated, but the report does NOT have any information on which environment(ST/ET/QA) the tests was run against .

**Is there any way to add environment/custom information to the report?**

Command:

```
Jmeter -n -t -Jenv="ST"   test.jmx  -l output.jtl  -e -o Dashboard    

test.jmx = script which is auto-generated
output.jtl = user defined file for output
Dashboard = user defined directory to store HTML dashboards
```

Comment: Please share you script or any other code you have done s far

Comment: @Günel test.jmx is the auto-generated file.
Eg: If i pass -Jenv="ST"  or -Jenv=ET , since its a standard report, it does NOT have any mentioning about environment (either ST or ET)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the [`jmeter.reportgenerator.report_title` property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#sample_configuration) so if you run the report generation as:

```
Jmeter -n -t -Jenv="ST" -Jjmeter.reportgenerator.report_title=ST -l output.jtl  -e -o Dashboard
```

[image]

More information:

- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Thanks for the asnwer @Dmitri T.
Out of curiosity, its still statically typed! i.e 
-Jjmeter.reportgenerator.report_title=ST
  Is there any option to set this propert during the execution of script (i,e   test.jmx  in my queestion )

Answer (score 0):

@Dmitri T shared the right link. One thing I want to add that you can choose what info to write to the logs through the Results tree settings. See the screenshot
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE23y.png)